# WCF Certificate Authentication without installing on the Client

Tags: wcf-security, digital-certificate

Our setup includes a WCF service and a number of clients written by us.  Some of the clients include Silverlight applications, whereas others include Web and Windows applications.

I (think) I would like to authenticate clients based on X.509 certificates.  Typically you would install a private key on the client to encrypt (aka digitaly sign) the messages.  The server can the use the clients public key to de-crypt it to ensure the message has not been changed and prove the message is from who we expect (aka authenticated).

I dont want to install a certificate on a client machine.  Its a hassel to deploy, and we cant really ask our clients to do it.  I was speaking to someone the other day who sugested embeding the cert in a client assembly, reading it and using that.  Is that possible?

It would be great if someone could point me to an example.

Thanks in advance,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can load [X509certificate2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx) by passing a certificate byte array with a password like

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(theByteArrary, "password");
```

To get the certificate byte array, you can simply copy paste the contents in .pfx file, which is a combination of .cer (public key) and .pvk (private key)

and then you can load this certificate on your client by doing:

```
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IYourService>();
channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = 
                                         clientCertificate;
```

If you use auto-generated client proxy, or you prefer configure the certificate via .config file then you might want to have a look at [this from codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcfcertificates.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion.  Could also be tweaked to use an embedded certificate.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcfcertificates.aspx